# Unexplainable mixed content warning - can non-secure cookies cause this?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, https

I have a page, https://uat03.i-grasp.com/fe/tpl_uat03_01_external.asp, which is coming up with a mixed content warning on IE. I can't reproduce it on Windows 7 but it is there for all versions in XP. When the cookie bar is disabled, the code to add it is no longer there and the warning ceases.

Absolutely ALL my resources are secure - the only thing I can think of which it could be is non-secure cookies, but if you don't specify them as secure then they can be picked up and set whether or not the site is secure, can't they?

Can someone see if they can shed some light on this please? I've spent 2 hours on this already, using Firebug, HTTPWatch, checking the source and all the files related to the cookie bar.. absolutely nothing is insecure.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer - for some reason IE was seeing relative links to CSS files as being non-secure. Changing these to include the protocol, server etc. appears to have fixed the issue. Why this occurs - bug in IE maybe? Wouldn't surprise me...

Comment: This was also the case for Chrome. However, Firefox/Seamonkey didn't complain. Nice catch @ClarkeyBoy!